# Delete Record in all tables in sql

Tags: sql

i want to delete all records related with student 'Petar Petrov' from ALL tables where records exist ( there are three tables )

Comment: Please add table structure, example data and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete-a-record-related-with-student-ivan-petrov-from-all-tables-where-such-re](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878624/)

Comment: You wanted to delete all records related to *Ivan Petrov* 2 minutes before you asked this question. :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878624/delete-a-record-related-with-student-ivan-petrov-from-all-tables-where-such-re

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you should use **cascading** `foreign keys` in your schema.

e.g:

```
create table students (
 id int,
 constraint pk_students primary key (id)
);

create table a(
 s_id int,
 constraint fk_a_student foreign key (s_id) references students on delete cascade
);

create table b(
 s_id int,
 constraint fk_b_student foreign key (s_id) references students on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using on delete cascade for Foreign Keys?

- [MSSQL](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/)
- [Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)
- [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: Convenient, until you make a mistake.